# Size of icons in Quick Access Toolbar (Ribbon) in Windows 10 Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, user-interface, dll

How can I change the size of the tiny icons in the Quick Access Toolbar (Ribbon, not to be confused with Quick Access folders) in Windows Explorer?

[image]

Possible directions to try:

- Opening `explorerframe.dll` with Reshacker or Restorator and navigating to `EXPLORER_RIBBON`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` (editable by [Advanced System Font Changer](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/advanced-system-font-changer), possibly related due to [this outdated article](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/change_ribbon_icon_and_font_size.html))
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Ribbon`

Answer (score 0):

Why not expanding the items of Home, Share and View by unchecking the feature of minimize the Robbin, which contains the icon of Properties and New a Folder?
[image]

I also searched a while but not capable to find methods to enlarge the icons of Robbin as you requested.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem for several reasons: The non-minimized Ribbon takes more space than a slightly enlarged Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) would; It has many other icons among which I'd have to look for mine; I want QAT icons that come from different tabs of the Ribbon, so finding them in the Ribbon takes even longer. Basically the reasons for which the QAT exists.